# PHP $_GET['myvar'] has different value than my URL parameter

Tags: php, url, get

in my url i have 2 parameters, the first 'art' which contains the product code, and 'cate' which contains the category assiociated to the product.

My `$_GET['art']` works just fine, it contains the good information and i can do every thing i need with it.

But my `$_GET['cate']` is broken :(

I'll explain, from which page you came from, cate could be set to 'DDI' 'TAB' or 'MAI'.
On the final page, the URL parameter is good, cate takes the good parameter.

Now my problem is, even if cate in the URL is set to cate=TAB or cate=MAI, the result of `$_GET['cate']` always show me 'DDI', instead of the URL parameter.

The URL looks like this  `domain/product.php?art=GD240BLC&cate=MAI`

I'm lost, need your help please.

Comment: Obviously it is changed somewhere in the code. Could You please provide code?

Comment: need more info post you sample code here

Comment: Please post some of the code you're using, there are a few things it could be, but it's hard to tell you what if we can't see your code. Also have you checked that the URL you're visiting does indeed have the correct value set in the query string? What happens if you manually type it out?

Comment: I think you need to post your code if you want help

Comment: make sure in your code that you aren't doing `if ( $_GET['cate'] = 'DDI' )` as that's a pretty common typo causing the value to be set rather than evaluated.

Comment: @DorianFM, you're right ! This was the problem, It was soooo obvious that I didn't figure it out. Thank you all, problem solved